# Change default screen keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, accessibility

In Ubuntu 18.04 the default screen keyboard is the regular Gnome on-screen keyboard. It can be activated via settings > universal access.

Does anybody know how to change the default on-screen keyboard launched via universal access?

E.g. I want to use [Florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html) or onboard, but they don't seem to work in the launcher when started as a regular program. When I open the launcher or activities those tools disappear, only the default Gnome on-screen keyboard shows up.